# Can we enable Cloudwatch logs for AWS Step Functions via terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

Can we enable logging in Cloudwatch for a AWS Step Function created via terraform to track individual states? The resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" available in terraform does not seem to provide any argument to configure Cloudwatch logging. As per documentation only below arguments are supported :

name,definition,role_arn,tags

or can we configure inside the state machine definition?

Comment: any update on this question?

Comment: @Cecilia Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66868788/2561119

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a property called `logging_configuration` : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sfn_state_machine . It was not possible before, but it was added in the AWS terraform provider >3.x , I don't remember the specific minor version it was added to so just make sure you have the latest version. Remember to also add the necessary permissions to your step function IAM role.

Comment: The documentation says this is only supported for `EXPRESS` but the example does not show an express step function. Does this works for `STANDARD` too?